# What is the worst webcam?

Tags: webcam

As many of you may know, the Coronavirus has stopped many of our lives. I, for one, am now taking college classes online. For many of my classes, I will need an webcam and microphone, although since most of my classes are just lectures, I don't necessarily feel the need to get an especially good webcam.

In fact, a webcam that has a lower resolution, higher sound compression, and I guess just all around terrible quality about it, would probably be better with the slower internet I now have use back at home. So, what is the worst webcam of all time?

Comment: I'd not drive for bad sound quality, as you do want to communicate effectively. Sound is typically 1/3 of bandwidth at decent quality, so it's not as important as video.